# Cast Exception when performing LINQ on IEnumerable

Tags: linq, types, casting, ienumerable, any

Let's say I have two classes,

```
class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

I have a method which accepts a parameter `foo` of type `IEnumerable<A>;`

```
void AMethod(IEnumerable<A> foo)
{
}
```

but instead pass in a value of type `IEnumerable<B>`.

```
AMethod(new[] { new B() });
```

This compiles and executes, though at execution `foo` has been implicitly cast to `IEnumerable<B>`. Now let's say my `IEnumerable<B>` contains objects of type A (I don't believe it matters whether they're mixed or all the same). When I call `foo.Any()` I get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'

I understand that I can't convert a base class to a subclass, but that's not what I'm trying to do (in fact at this point in execution, I don't even care what type it is). I guess LINQ is inherently trying to make this conversion, probably based on the fact that `foo` is type `IEnumerable<B>`. So, it seems as though I need to write two separate methods, one which handles `IEnumerable<A>` and one which handles `IEnumerable<B>`.  I don't understand why I would need to do this.  Any thoughts?

EDIT:

There's some dynamic casting and transformation going on that manages to spit out a `IEnumerable<B>` populated with 'A's, which until now I thought was impossible too. I'll do my best to translate what's happening leading up to this method call:

```
protected void SetDynamicData(dynamic data)
{
  _data = data;
  IsB = typeof(IBInterface).IsAssignableFrom(_data.DataType);
}
```

...

```
var foo = IsB ? _data.Cast<B>() : data.Cast<A>();
return BuildJqGridData<A, B, int>(gridModel, foo);
```

Comment: If B inherits A then a B is an A but an A is not a B.

Comment: How does `IEnumerable<B>` contain an object of type `A`? Can you post a small code snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've updated you question, without changing its meaning to make it more readable.

Comment: Your example is not the same as your question. In your example, you are passing an `IEnumerable<B>` with one item of type `B`. This will work

Comment: what type is `_data`?

Comment: @Aducci data contains a set of objects already set to type A or B.  The logic responsible for setting `IsB`, and consequently the type, is asking "are all objects in this set assignable to B?" by checking whether they can be assigned to `IBInterface`.  If it finds any reason not to, it will default to `IEnumerable<A>` which is causing the problem.  I'm not sure what reason it has for denying that, which is probably where I need to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IEnumerable<B>` cannot contain objects of type `A` because and `A` is not a `B`.

I can write this code,

```
IEnumerable<B> dodgy = (new[] { new A() }).Cast<B>();
```

It will compile, despite being obviously wrong. The compiler assumes I know what I'm doing. Remember that no item in the `IEnumerable` sequence has yet been evaluated.

When I write code that evaluates a member of `dodgy` I get exception because an `A` is not a `B` and does not support casting to `B`.

I can write

```
IEnumerable<A> fine = new[] { new B() };
```

no cast is required and everything works fine because a `B` is an `A`.

---

If I do,

```
var hungrilyDodgy = (new[] { new A() }).Cast<B>().ToList();
```

the `Tolist()` will force enumeration and evaluation of the `IEnumerable`, therefore the exception will be thrown much sooner.

Comment: I think that's what I'm seeing.  It appears the code I'm working with is taking a very roundabout way of accomplishing what you have there, using conditions to decide its type.  Somehow, I made it choose incorrectly.

Just to confirm, when you use that at run time you can successfully create 'dodgy' and pass it around, you just can't do anything with it?  If so, you've got the right answer (and my thanks).

Comment: @user2339577, thats right, no evaluation takes place until the `IEnumerable` is enumerated. All the compiler knows is that `Cast<>()` returns a compatible type. In your case it fails and throws an exception.